# "necessary to life" OR "necessary for life"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

From Longman dictionary I see that the word *necessary* can be used as follows:

> It is necessary (for somebody) to do something.
>
> Something is necessary for (doing) something.

However, I saw the sentence

> Air is necessary ***to*** life;

in a book which I think should be

> Air is necessary ***for*** life.

Which form is correct and why?

Comment: https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/necessary-for-in-to-at-by/

Comment: It seems that both are used. According to the link, in 67% of cases *necessary for* is used and in  9% of cases *necessary to* (not sure what cases have been considered). However, 67% also includes *for X to do Y* cases.

Comment: You must also keep context in mind.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine  Interestingly, half of those "necessary to" examples are wrong, because the "to" is actually just for the infinitive verb that follows "necessary."

Comment: I would take the examples on that page with a grain of salt, because many of the prepositions actually modify the phrase after "necessary" and not "necessary" itself.

Comment: @Ringo I know, hence "You must also keep context in mind.".

Comment: In the vast majority of contexts, ***necessary to life, necessary for life, essential to life*** and ***essential for life*** are all equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: @Ringo: Haha - ***food is necessary to live***, as well as being ***...necessary to life**!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> X is necessary for Y

This expresses a prerequisite.  Here, you are saying that if you don't have Y, you can't have X.

> X is necessary to Y

This can be interpreted as "Y believes X is necessary", but this may not match what you think is necessary or what actually is necessary.

In the case of life, air is objectively necessary (for some life anyway), so you can say *to* or *for*.

Comment: "... if you don't have Y, you can't have X" should be "... if you don't have X, you can't have Y".

Answer (score 0):

To is used after necessary not only before infinitive but also for condition.

> It is necessary to the happiness of man to live in comfort.